# Spring MVC + Before Advice check security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, aspectj

I'm testing Spring AOP framework and have the following question.

I have the following code:

```
package danny.test.controllers;

@Controller
public class MyController{

@Autowired
private DaoService service;

@RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public String addUser(@Valid MyClass myClass, BindingResult result){

service.save(myClass);

return "Ok";
}
```

I would like to create before Advice aspect to check user security in user session.

```
@Aspect
public class Profiler {

    @Pointcut("execution(* danny.test.services.DaoServices.*.*(..))")
    public void methods(){}

    @Before("methods()")
    public void checkSecurity() throws Throwable{
        //check session if user is authenticated....
    }

}
```

What I don't know what to do is to cancel execution of DaoServices.save method if the user is not authenticated and cause controller to return any other value instead of "ok".

Can i do it? 
Can someone point me to such example? 
Can I use @Around advice for such actions?

Comment: I'm just curious, why are you not using Spring Security for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think you should use the @Around advice and just not call the `ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed()` method if the authentication fails.

**UPDATE:**

To return something else your method should look something like this:

```
@Before("methods()")
public Object checkSecurity(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
    if (/*user is authenticated*/) {
        return pjp.proceed();
    } else {
        return "NOT OK";
    }
}
```

Please notice that the method returns an object. See also this part of the Spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-schema-advice-around).

Comment: Yes, Thanks I have found it by myself as well :) thanks a lot.