# How to catch exception in Join point which was thrown from @Around

Tags: java, spring, security, aspectj, spring-aop

Following up with this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248716/conditional-behavior-of-spring-aop-before-advice#comment16421693_12249543) of my previous question. I'm trying to throw an exception from the `@Around` advice, and catch it within the callee class and/or method. But I'm getting this error:

```
Stacktraces

java.lang.Exception: User not authorized
    com.company.aspect.AuthorizeUserAspect.isAuthorized(AuthorizeUserAspect.java:77)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    ...
```

The Aspect code is:

```
@Aspect
public class AuthorizeUserAspect {
    @AuthoWired
    private UserService service;

    @Pointcut("@annotation(module)")
    public void authorizeBeforeExecution(AuthorizeUser module) {}

    @Around(value = "authorizeBeforeExecution(module)", argNames="module")
    public Object isAuthorized(ProceddingJoinPoint jp, AuthorizeUser module) throws Throwable {
        // Check if the user has permission or not
        service.checkUser();

        if ( /* User has NOT permission */ ) {
            throw new MyCustomException("User not authorized"); // => this is line 77
        }

        return jp.proceed();
    }
}
```

and the Struts's based UI action code is:

```
@Component
public class DashboardAction extends ActionSupport {
    @Override
    @AuthorizeUser
    public String execute() {
        ...
    }

    private void showAccessDenied() {
       ...
    }
}
```

The question is How or Where I can catch that exception to execute `showAccessDenied()`?

Answer (score 2):

To handle uncaught exceptions like `MyCustomException` you need to define a global exception handler in Struts 2. Please check this guide: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/exception-handling.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've managed to do this before, but the thing is I can not do Action-specific manipulation to catched exception with Global Exception. Isn't there a way to catch it in the specified class? Because I have Jersey type of interface as well, besides Struts's based.

Comment: Since your code is throwing an exception in `@Around` advice which you can trap in your custom code in the `@AfterThrowing` advice.

Answer (score 0):

For user interface I'd recommend writing a short code for catching any uncaught exceptions.

```
class EventQueueProxy extends EventQueue {
    @Override
    protected void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent newEvent) {
        try {
            super.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            String message = t.getMessage();
            if (message == null || message.length() == 0) {
                message = "Fatal: " + t.getClass();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Unhandled Exception Caught!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the ui class:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    EventQueue queue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
    queue.push(new EventQueueProxy());

    //your code goes here...
}
```

Note, it will show the dialog window with an error information each time uncaught exception appears. This is just the suggestion for your ui, for the particular case of your ploblem, do use *try* for firing method(s) that authorizes a user and *catch* for firing method(s) that should be executed if the user is not authorized. in such case authorization method should throw an exception if an authorization fails. Then the error will not be printed but the particular method will be fired instead.

That's what I'd add to your code:

```
@Component 
public class DashboardAction extends ActionSupport {
    @Override
    try {
        @AuthorizeUser
        public String execute() {
                 ...     
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        private void showAccessDenied() {
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "catching any uncaught exceptions"? any exceptions from Application Layer and below?

Comment: any exceptions that interupts ui class

Comment: This exception is thrown "before" ui method execution. isn't it? But it surely interrupts it. would you mind to provide that suggestion code of yours?

Comment: Oh no! You have got it all wrong. it's a Web-based application and the ui is consists of Struts's actions and Jersey Resources.

Comment: i see, i've edited the answer again. check the last block of code example